# How to create a batch file that will delete lines in a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I hope you can help me on how to create a windows batch file that will delete lines in a text file with occurrence of s string in a specific position (col). After deleting, it will put all the remaining lines in a new text file.

Comment: Start with `For /F "tokens=*" %G in (your-file.TXT) do @echo %G` to get an initial look to processing of a text file. Then learn how-to [extract part of a variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html), on [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all lines from input.txt where someString appears in column 10:

```
findstr /rvc:"^.........someString" input.txt >output.txt
```

`/r` forces a regular expression interpretation

`/v` returns lines that don't match

`/c:"..."` specifies the regular expression search string

`^` anchors the search at the beginning of the line

`.........` matches any 9 characters

Comment: this is what ive been looking for. Just a follow up, what if my text file is inside a folder and the filename can be anything. I tried to replace "input.txt" to a directory but it's not working

Comment: You will need a FOR /F loop that processes the output of DIR /B. The FINDSTR command will be run for each file iterated. Presumably the output name will be a derivative of the input. There are many examples demonstrating the concept on this site.